# Get Date Value as DD/MM/YYYY from database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am using the *"[Datatype(Datatype.date)"* data annotation for allowing the user to select the date and it's selected in this format, *"DD/MM/YYYY"*.

However, the date is sent backwards to the database. The image below illustrates this.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

[Correct date selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnKni.png)

[Backwards date sent to data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWTBu.png)

Comment: That is just the way its represented in the database.

Comment: Don't worry, the date value displayed in DB table is just a string representation of inserted date from your app. The exact value in DB doesn't changed.

Comment: `ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(50), ColumName, 100), 'N/A') As ColumName`
try using this for displaying Date as i have converted it to DD MM YYYY format you can you it in your select Query

Comment: This has very little to do with the database and everything to do with whatever tool you are using to represent it. The first step is to confirm what data type you are using in the database, then actually look at the data in the database and confirm whether it's correct or not. If it's correct in the database, the issue is with the display format. If it's incorrect in the database, the issue is in the datepicker you are using, or the way you post it to your controller.

Comment: I understand it's the datepicker used in the data annotations but cannot find a way to alter it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended off using Moment which is amazing at formatting dates.